# Best practice to cleanup resources acquired by an Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka

My Akka actor acquires some resources, which should be released after jobs are done, as shown by code snippet below.
The issue is, how to make sure the resources will be released in case of exceptions.
The first idea occurred to me is to assign the acquired resources to a `var`, and release them in `def postStop()` hook as a safeguard.

As this is a such common requirement, I'm wondering if there's any best practice to this?

```scala
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case FILEIO(path) => {
      val ios = fs.create(new Path(path))
      // ios.read/write ..
      // exception could occur
      ios.close()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use scala 2.13 you can try [scala.util.Using](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html). It will close the resource automatically even if an exception occurs.

```
val resultTry = Using(fs.create(new Path(path))) { ios =>
    // ios.read/write ..
    // exception could occur
}
resultTry match {
   case Success(ioOperationsResult) => ...
   case Failure(ioException) => ...
}
```

Also, you should separate blocking IO operations from the akka dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Use Akka Stream's [File IO sinks and sources](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/index.html#file-io-sinks-and-sources). The `FileIO` tools use actors under the covers, transparently close resources when errors occur, and run on a dedicated dispatcher. The latter is important because blocking IO operations should be isolated from the rest of the system. A simple example from the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/stream-io.html#streaming-file-io):

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
val file = Paths.get("example.csv")

val foreach: Future[IOResult] = FileIO.fromPath(file).to(Sink.ignore).run()
```

Comment: Yes, I do use akka streams. Currently, I create an open file handler os outside of the stream pipeline and connect it to source like .runForeach(s => os.write(s)). I'll change it to using akka hdfs sink and eliminate the os. But the resource releasing is a general requirement, and I'm just taking file stream as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider using actors for heavy IO access. 
Given that you're using a default dispatcher, you might block it with IO operations and this will slow down the whole actor system.

If you still wish to proceed, recommend doing following

- Create a new dispatcher and assign it to your actor. See [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#setting-the-dispatcher-for-an-actor) for reference
- Use try/finally block to close resources (yes, plain old try/catch/finally)

```
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case FILEIO(path) => {
      val ios = fs.create(new Path(path))
      try {
        // ios.read/write ..
        // exception could occur
      } finally {
        ios.close()
      }
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, extract your IO work into async context, like `Future` that should be executed in a dedicated execution context and use `pipeTo` pattern to process results with an Actor.

Comment: Thanks! I'll create a dedicated dispatcher for IO actors. And I prefer akka streams for these kinds of IO. As for resource releasing, the plain try/catch works. I'm just not sure if there's any better approach in scala & akka world.